# Proof of Abel's Criterion (Uniform)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm having lots of problems finding a full proof (which doesn't depend on other theorems even more complicated to prove) of this theorem, with my exact hypothesis which are:

1. The series $\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}a_{n}$ is convergent.
2. For all $z\in A$ $\{f_{n}(z)\}$ is a monotone sequence of real numbers and the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ is bounded uniformly contained in $A$.

Then the series of functions $\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}a_{n}f_{n}$ converge uniformly in A.

The thing is that I find proofs but either they miss some important steps or they don't match my exact hypothesis. Could someone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the 2 versions of summation by parts which express $\sum {a_kb_k}$ where $b_k$ monotonic in terms of partial sums of the $a_k$ and successive differences of the $b_k$ depending whether $b_k$ increases or decreases?

for example one such (the one that is seen "less usually" which is for increasing $b$) being:

$a_Nb_N+...a_Mb_M=a_M(b_M-b_{M-1})+(a_M+a_{M-1})(b_{M-1}-b_{M-2})+....(a_M+a_{M-1}+...a_{N+1})(b_{N+1}-b_N)+(a_M+a_{M-1}+...a_N)b_N$

Applying the appropriate one for $k=N,....,M$ for large $M>N$ depending whether $f_k(z)$ increases or decreases you get a uniform inequality of the type $|\sum_{N \le k \le M}{a_kf_k(z)}| \le 2FA_{N,M}$, where $F$ is a uniform bound for $|f_k(z)|$ and $A_{N,M}=max_{N\le p\le q \le M} |\sum_{p \le k \le q}{a_k}|$

convergence of $a_k$ means $A_{N,M} \to 0$ by Cauchy-criterion, so the inequality above means $\sum_{N \le k \le M}{a_kf_k(z)}$ uniformly Cauchy, hence $\sum{a_kf_k(z)}$ uniformly convergent